# SSR Next.js don't provides plain HTML, but JS

Tags: javascript, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering, redux-persist

I am using `"next": "^12.2.3"`, `"react": "^18.2.0"`, and `"typescript": "^4.7.4"` for a web app.

If I use SSR mode in `next.js`, I see only the metatags in pure HTML, but a javascript object wraps all the other content. This is not readable/seo friendly for the search engines)

If I use the `next export`, I can see the pure HTML (readable from any search engine)

So, more or less, the question here is:
if there is any way to have SSR or even SSG or Incremental SSG, and the source code in the client/browser to be pure HTML?

---

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { useStore } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';
import initializeApollo from '@/graphql';
import { wrapper } from '../src/store';
import { setClientState } from '../src/store/redux-models/common/actions';
import theme from '../src/theme/theme';
import createEmotionCache from '../src/createEmotionCache';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import EnvValidation from '/src/utils/env-validator';

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  EnvValidation();
}

// Client-side cache, shared for the whole session of the user in the browser.
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

if (typeof process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_MOCKING !== 'undefined') {
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_MOCKING === 'enabled') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    require('@/mocks');
  }
}

function MyApp({
  Component,
  emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache,
  pageProps,
}) {
  const store = useStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(setClientState());
  }, []);

  Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
    NProgress.start();
  });

  Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
    NProgress.done();
  });

  return (
    <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor}>
      <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <ApolloProvider client={initializeApollo()}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </ApolloProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </PersistGate>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Comment: Next.js does return plain HTML when server-side rendering pages, and it's perfectly SEO-friendly. Could you be clearer on the issue you're seeing? Where do you see this _"javascript object wraps all the other content"_?

Comment: @juliomalves I can give you an example of what I mean. 
this is an example of SSR with next.js https://nextjs-ssr-real-world-example.herokuapp.com/ . Once I check the source code, I can see the content on any components. 
Eg. I can see the text -> `A place to share your knowledge` wrapped by a `<p>` tag.  However, once I do the same to my application, i see the no `<p>` tag or any HTML tag, but I see the `A place to share your knowledge.` string into the `__NEXT_DATA__` json only..

Comment: @juliomalves
more or less, I see only the head metatags in my HTML, but no content between the components. 
Actually, I don't even see the components on the source code. I have to check it via the `inspect`  and inspect a specific component but not via the source code of the browser.

Comment: tbh, I am not so sure if what I experience in SSR (and on SSG) is the correct result. /shrug

Comment: What's inside the `__NEXT_DATA__` script is simply the data required for hydration on the client, but the HTML will still be generated on the server with that data too. Unless you're forcing the Next.js app to render on the client-side only, the HTML should appear on the page source. Can you show us the code of your application? Mainly, can you show us what you have in the `_app` page?

Comment: @juliomalves 

I believe that something is wrong with my application on the configs in the _app.js. somewhere, because even if I use SSR or SSG, I have the SPA experience. I've updated the post.

Comment: It's because of the `PersistGate`, it forces the app to render on the client-side only. See this GH discussion for potential solutions: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8240#issuecomment-647699316.

Comment: Thanks for that man @juliomalves  At least now i have a reference and that i know that what I experience in not normal :)

Comment: That is true, when you use SSR with dynamic routing [...slug] its create a huge json data with all fetched texts of all pages in this dynamic routing. That is imao a real problem for seo, its dublicate the content of all pages in each page.

Answer (score -2):

Neither `next dev` nor `next build` generate SPA bundles, both of them generate SSR'd HTML, `<h1>...</h1>` and so on. The only runtime script you are seeing is the [hydration logic](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate).